# Bound on expectation of random variable with atom at zero

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm reading the literature on mixing for stochastic processes. An inequality is used repeatedly, but it's never proven explicitly. [See, for example, [Lemma 2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RskQU.jpg) in Davydov (1968), or [part (1-ii)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUwlQ.jpg) of the proof of Theorem 3 in Doukhan (1994).] My attempts to prove it myself has failed so far, so I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

Let $X$ be a random variable so that $X \geq 0$ a.s. and $E[X^p] < \infty$ for some $p > 1$. Let $Y = \mathbb{1}_{(X \geq a)} X$ for some constant $a$ where $\mathbb{1}_{(X \geq a)}$ is an indicator whether $X$ is greater or equal to $a$.

The bound that's used in the literature is:

$$E[Y] \leq \frac{E[X^p]}{a^{\,p-1}}.$$

A possible way forward would be:

$$E[Y] = E[X | X \geq a]Pr(X \geq a) \leq E[X | X \geq a] \frac{E[X^p]}{a^{\,p}},$$

where the last inequality follows from Markov's inequality. However, we would require that $E[X | X \geq a]\leq a$ to get the expectation bound,  which obviously is false.

Any ideas on how to go about proving this?

[Davydov, Y. A. (1968). Convergence of distributions generated by stationary stochastic processes. Theory of Probability & Its Applications, 13(4), 691-696.](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1113086)

[Doukhan, P. (1994). Mixing. Springer New York.](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-2642-0)

Comment: Integrate the almost sure inequality $$a^{p-1}Y\leqslant X^p$$

Comment: @Did So obvious when you point it out! Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Post this as an answer?

Comment: @Did Yes, it was exactly what I was looking for. I would post it as an answer myself, but I don't want to steal your thunder.