# strong mixing and correlation decay

Tags: probability-theory, independence, covariance

Given a sequence $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, suppose there exists a function $\alpha$ such that for each $n$ and $N$,
\begin{equation}
\sup \left\{ |P(A\cap B) - P(A)P(B)| : A \in \mathcal{F}_{X_1, \dots X_n}, B\in \mathcal{F}_{X_{n+k}, \dots, X_{N}}\right\} \leq \alpha(k).
\end{equation}
If $\alpha(k)\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$, then we say the sequence is strong mixing.

I am interested in the following statement which uses the covariance: there exists a function $\beta$ such that for each sequence of real numbers$\{a_i\}$, each integers $k\geq 1$,  $n$, $N$
\begin{equation}
\text{Cov}\Big(\log \Big(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \prod_{k=1}^i X_k\Big), \log \Big(\sum_{j=n+k}^N a_j \prod_{l=n+k}^j X_l\Big)\Big) \leq \beta(k).
\end{equation}

Is there any connection between the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ defined above? For example, does the $\alpha$ bound imply the $\beta$ bound? If not, what would be a stronger assumption for $\alpha$ so that $\beta$ holds?

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide uniform moment bounds
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\log\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \prod_{k=1}^i X_k\right)^p\right]^{1/p} \le C_1; \qquad \mathbb{E}\left[\log\left(\sum_{j=n+k}^N a_j \prod_{l=n+k}^j X_l\right)^q\right]^{1/q} \le C_2$$
for some $p, q \ge 1$ such that $1 - \frac 1p - \frac 1q > 0$, then Davydov's inequality (see e.g. [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390436/bound-on-expectation-of-random-variable-with-atom-at-zero) or [thm. 1.2.3 in the book *Mixing* by Doukhan (1994)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-2642-0) for a reference) implies you can take
$$\beta(k) = 8 C_1 C_2 \alpha(k)^{1 - 1/p - 1/q}.$$